# How to read lines of text from file and put them into an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I created a text file `love.txt`:

```
i love you
you love me
```

How do I store them into separate array, namely `line1` and `line2` and then display them out in console?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string line1[30];
  string line2[30];
  ifstream myfile("love.txt");
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;
  if(!myfile) 
  {
    cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
  }
  while(!myfile.eof())
  {
    getline(myfile,line1[a],' ');
    cout<<"1."<<line1[a]<<"\n";
    getline(myfile,line2[b],' ');
    cout<<"2."<<line2[b]<<"\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are really trying to write C++ code, maybe you should consider using std::vector<std::string> instead of those `evil` arrays...

Comment: std::vector<std::string> std wasnt taught in my lesson yet and I dun know how to use them.

Comment: I see. Well, it's dead simple, but if you can't use them, then you need a counter which increments after each call to `getline` in the while loop. You should use a multidimensional array like matrix[2][30] and then you will insert your string in matrix[counter]. If the teacher sticks to arrays and pointers, maybe he should specify that the course is about C, not C++. If you're curious about std::vector<std::string>, well, it allows you to do something like this: `std::string data; cin >> data; vector.push_back(data);` inside the loop. Then you can just iterate over the vector to print it.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you use string instead of char *. My rant above applies to char *matrix[2][30]. Just follow Attila's suggestion, after you read a decent C++ tutorial... The `using namespace std;` statement is not there for nothing ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying the last argument as **'\n'**  in both `getline()` functions:

```
getline(myfile, line1[a], '\n');
```

instead of

```
getline(myfile, line1[a], ' ');
```

Comment: Or just don't specify the last parameter: it defaults to new-line

Comment: @Attila In above code it is space so I have differentiate it.

Comment: WOW! this method work thanks...
but why is that so with just a \n it read and store 2nd line into another array

Comment: @user1526669 Because you had specify space as delimiter character and you want to delimited by new line(\n).

Comment: @user - if you use Mahesh's approach, you can have words that contain newline characters as that will not be recognized by the `getline()` when you set the delimiter to space (` `)

Answer (score 6):

How about this.. .

```
vector <string> v;
string line;    
ifstream fin("love.txt");
while(getline(fin,line)){
    v.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a string as an array of characters, so you will only need one array of strings:

```
const size_t SIZE = 30;
string line[SIZE]; // creates SIZE empty strings
size_t i=0;
while(!myfile.eof() && i < SIZE) {
  getline(myfile,line[i]); // read the next line into the next string
  ++i;
} 

for (i=0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
  if (!line[i].empty()) { // print only if there is something in the current line
    cout << i << ". " << line[i];
  }
}
```

You could maintain a counter to see how many lines you have stored into (instead of checking for empty lines) as well -- this way you will properly print empty lines as well:

```
const size_t SIZE = 30;
string line[SIZE]; // creates SIZE empty strings
size_t i=0;
while(!myfile.eof() && i < SIZE) {
  getline(myfile,line[i]); // read the next line into the next string
  ++i;
}
size_t numLines = i;

for (i=0; i < numLines; ++i) {
  cout << i << ". " << line[i]; // no need to test for empty lines any more
}
```

*Note*: you will be able to store only up to `SIZE` lines.  If you need more, you will have to increase `SIZE` in the code.  Later on you will learn about `std::vector<>` that allows you to dynamically grow the size as needed (so you won't need to keep track of how many you stored).

*Note*: the use of constants like `SIZE` allows you to change the size in one place only

*Note*: you should add a check for errors in the input stream on top of `eof()`: in case there was a read failure other than reaching the end of the file:

```
while (myfile && ...) {
  // ...
}
```

here `myfile` is converted to a boolean value indicating if it is OK to use it (`true`) or not (`false`)

---

**Update**:

I just realized what you are after:  you want to read the input as series of words (separated by space), but display them as lines.  In this case, you will need arrays-of-arrays to store each line

```
string line[SIZE1][SIZE2];
```

where `SIZE1` is the maximum amount of lines you can store and `SIZE2` is the maximum amount of words you can store per line

Filling this matrix will be more complex: you will need to read the input line-by-line then separate the words within the line:

```
string tmp; // temporary string to store the line-as-string
getline(myfile, tmp);
stringstream ss(tmp); // convert the line to an input stream to be able to extract
                      // the words
size_t j=0; // the current word index
while (ss) {
  ss >> line[i][j]; // here i is as above: the current line index
  ++j;
}
```

Output:

```
for (i=0; i < numLines; ++i) {
  cout << i << ". ";
  for (size_t j=0; j < SIZE2; ++j) {
    if (!line[i][j].empty()) {
      cout << line[i][j] << " ";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MihaiTodor - yes, I realized it during my later edits, should be fixed now

Comment: thanks but those code are too advance for me....
declaration such as "const size_t" is new to me..

Comment: @user1526669 - `const` means you cannot change the value -- protects you from some coding mistakes (you can leave it out if you have not learned this feature yet); `size_t` is an unsinged (non-negative) integer -- I used it as the line numbers cannot be negative (you can use `int` just as well if you don't know `size_t` yet);  The updated version uses `std::stringstream`, which will most likely too advanced for you, but I cannot think of a more basic way to achieve the extraction otherwise, sort of going through the input line character by character and that will be messy

Comment: with this \n it solved my beginner problem, the approach suggested above hasnt been taught so it would be pretty difficult for me to apply them.  thx

Answer (score 0):

My complete solution.

the config.txt file contains:

```
#URL WEB POP3 IMAP SMTP FTP DNS PING ORDER
st-xxxx.com 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
24.xxx.195.11 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 2
24.xxx.195.12 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 3
192.168.0.100 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 4
```

and my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  ifstream myfile("config.txt");
  if(!myfile)
  {
    cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
  }

    const size_t SIZE1 = 30;
    const size_t SIZE2 = 10;
    string line[SIZE1][SIZE2];

    string tmp; // temporary string to store the line-as-string

    size_t i=0; // the current line index
    size_t j=0; // the current word index


    while(!myfile.eof() && i < SIZE1) {
    getline(myfile, tmp);
    stringstream ss(tmp); // convert the line to an input stream to be able 
//to extract the words
    size_t j=0;
    while (ss) {
      ss >> line[i][j]; // here i is as above: the current line index
      ++j;
    }
    i++;
    }

    size_t numLines = i;

    cout << numLines << "\n";
for (i=1; i <= numLines; ++i) {

  for (size_t j=0; j < SIZE2; ++j) {
    if (!line[i][j].empty()) {
      cout << line[i][j] << " ";
    }
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
    cout << line[3][0] << "\n"; // print the third line first word
}
```

Hope tht helps anybody who is searching for this type of solution, even if the post is quite old.