# Reading from a text file and then using the input in the program

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I want to have a program read a text file with 5 double digit numbers, that are on separate lines. I want to then have the those numbers placed in the program where the lowest number will be dropped and the remaining 4 numbers will be averaged and then output on the screen.

The text file is just a notepad .txt file with:

```
83
71
94
62
75
```

I have successfully constructed the program where I can manually enter the numbers and it will do as I wanted, but my knowledge of using files within the code is limited. I have read about vectors but I would like to keep it simple first and get the hang of it before I try to learn something else. I have tried to set up a some code that resembles what I think it should probably look like. My question is, : Why am I getting a ""error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter"" with my debugging?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


//function prototypes 
void getScore(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5);
void calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5);
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5);

int main()
{
getScore(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
return 0;
}

//function to collect the 5 test scores 
void getScore(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
string line1[30];
string line2[30];
string line3[30];
string line4[30];
string line5[30];
ifstream myfile("grades.txt");
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;
int s3 = 0;
int s4 = 0;
int s5 = 0;
if(!myfile) 

cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
system("pause");
return -1;

while(!myfile.eof())

getline(myfile,line1[s1],'\n');
cin >> s1;

getline(myfile,line2[s2],'\n');
cin >> s2;

getline(myfile,line3[s3],'\n');
cin >> s3;

getline(myfile,line4[s4],'\n');
cin >> s4;

getline(myfile,line5[s5],'\n');
cin >> s5;

calcAverage(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
}




//function to calculate the average of the 4 highest test scores 
void calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
int average;
int lowest;
lowest = findLowest(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
average = ((s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5) - lowest)/4;
cout << endl;
cout << "The average of the four highest test scores is: ";
cout << average << endl;
}
//function to find the lowest test score 
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
int lowest = s1;

if (s2<lowest)
lowest = s2;
if (s3<lowest)
lowest = s3;
if (s4<lowest)
lowest = s4;
if (s5<lowest)
lowest = s5;
return lowest;
return 0;
}
```

Build results:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: droplowest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  lowest drop.cpp
1>c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest          drop.cpp(33): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 's1'
1>c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest drop.cpp(34): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 's2'
1>c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest drop.cpp(35): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 's3'
1>c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest drop.cpp(36): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 's4'
1>c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest drop.cpp(37): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 's5'
1>c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest drop.cpp(42): error C2562: 'getScore' : 'void' function returning a value
1>          c:\users\ldw\documents\visual studio    2010\projects\droplowest\droplowest\lowest drop.cpp(14) : see declaration of 'getScore'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: Is there any reason you've used no braces in the getScore function?  I would have thought that this: if(!myfile) 

cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
system("pause");
return -1;  should be if(!myfile) {
cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
system("pause");
return -1;}  As the code is at the moment, it is always going to run system pause and then return -1, never even try and read the text file

Comment: Can you show us an example of the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read lines of text from file and put them into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546177/how-to-read-lines-of-text-from-file-and-put-them-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error about redefinition of formal parameters because in `getScore` you are redefining `s1` through `s5`. The five scores are given as arguments to `getScore`, so you don't have to define them again. You can just use them.

To have your program read from the file instead of you manually entering the scores, simply change each `cin >> s#;` to `myfile >> s#;` (where you replace `#` with the actual numbers 1-5). `cin` and `myfile` are both streams, so you can use them in the same way. They just read from different places.

I would change your `getScore` function to look like this:

```
//function to collect the 5 test scores 
void getScore(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
    ifstream myfile("grades.txt");

    if (!myfile) 
    {
        cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        return;
    }

    myfile >> s1;
    myfile >> s2;
    myfile >> s3;
    myfile >> s4;
    myfile >> s5;

    calcAverage(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
}
```

Note that I changed your `return -1;` to just `return;`. This is because `getScore` is defined as returning nothing (`void`). So you have to return nothing. Also, you don't need to have all of the `getline`s.

Note also that in your `findLowest` function, you have multiple returns at the end. Only the first one will be used, since a return means that that is the end of the function. I would remove the second one like this:

```
//function to find the lowest test score 
int findLowest(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
    int lowest = s1;

    if (s2 < lowest)
        lowest = s2;
    if (s3 < lowest)
        lowest = s3;
    if (s4 < lowest)
        lowest = s4;
    if (s5 < lowest)
        lowest = s5;
    return lowest;
}
```

In order to make your program easier to modify (what if you want to read/process more numbers later?), you would want to use fixed-size arrays (not vectors) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_SCORES = 5;

//function prototypes
void getScores(string filename);
void calcAverage(int* scores);
int findLowest(int* scores);

int main()
{
    getScore("grades.txt");
    return 0;
}

//function to collect the test scores 
void getScores(string filename)
{
    int scores[NUM_SCORES] = { 0 }; // initialize all of the scores to 0.

    ifstream myfile(filename);

    if(!myfile) 
    {
        cout << "Error opening output file." << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES && !myfile.eof(); i++)
        myfile >> scores[i];
    if (i != NUM_SCORES)
    {
        // this means that there weren't enough numbers in the file.
        cout << "Not enough numbers in the file." << endl;
        system("pause>nul");
        return;
    }

    calcAverage(scores);
}

//function to calculate the average of the every test score but the lowest 
void calcAverage(int* scores)
{
    int lowest = findLowest(scores);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; i++)
        sum += scores[i];
    sum -= lowest;
    int average = sum / (NUM_SCORES - 1);

    cout << endl << "The average of the four highest test scores is: " << average << endl;
}
//function to find the lowest test score 
int findLowest(int* scores)
{
    int lowest = scores[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < NUM_SCORES; i++)
        if (scores[i] < lowest)
            lowest = scores[i];

    return lowest;
}
```

Also note that in `calcAverage`, you don't need to define all of your variables at the beginning of the function. In C++, you can define them anywhere in a block.

Comment: Thank you Jashaszun. That was exactly what I was trying to do. I appreciate you taking the time and helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/).

```
myfile.open();
if(!myfile.is_open()) 
{
  cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
  system("pause");
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: May also be worth adding that braces are needed to surround the while(!myfile.eof()) block as its currently just gonna constantly consume line1[s1]

Comment: There's not really much reason to make a call to the OS just for system("pause") in this case. You've already included iostream, request user input instead of that call...

Answer (score 0):

Didn't go through the entire code. But as the error suggests u have re-declared the int s1 , s2 , s3 , s4, s5.

Try changing the following

```
ifstream myfile("grades.txt");
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;
int s3 = 0;
int s4 = 0;
int s5 = 0;
```

To

```
ifstream myfile("grades.txt");
s1 = 0;
s2 = 0;
s3 = 0;
s4 = 0;
s5 = 0;
```

As these variables are already declared in the function parameter list.

```
void getScore(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5)
{
  ...
```

You cannot declare them. Its not allowed in C++.

Comment: Thanks Genocide_Hoax, and others for your responses.

Comment: Genocide that seems to be a big piece of my errors. I now have some others to sort through.

Comment: Just one one question: drop.cpp(42): error C2562: 'getScore' : 'void' function returning a value

Comment: change the following:
if(!myfile) 

cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
system("pause");
return -1;  to 

if(!myfile) 
{
cout<<"Error opening output file"<<endl;
system("pause");
exit(0); // Add header stdlib.h
}

Answer (score 0):

In the function prototype you just have the datatype of the formal parameters.

```
void getScore(int,int,int,int,int)
```

And you have redefined them into `int s1=0;`. Just do `s1=0;`.